# How do I adjust the camera exposure on my iSight?

Tags: macos, mac, webcam, external-display, isight

My iSight camera defaults to a too-low exposure, which means my face is washed-out when I'm on a video call. Is there a way to adjust the camera exposure for the iSight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no internal adjustment.

I don't have an iSight, but for my Logitech C920 I use [Webcam Settings](https://itunes.apple.com/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) which also says it supports the iSight.
No affiliation.

Comment: Thanks! I also came across iGlasses (http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses)